# Call the build script present on another machine

Tags: networking, ant

We have a build script present on our build machine.

How will I run this build script from my machine using `ant`?

Both machines are in same network.

Is there any free tool to call build script on remote machine which supports command line support?

**Please Note:** Build script cannot be called manually.

Please ask for any more details are required.

Comment: I'd highly recommend setting up Jenkins to run builds on remote machines.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Jenkins is an integration server. We need such tool which will invoke the script stored on another machine and which should have command line support.

Comment: Yes Jenkins can do this. You setup a Jenkins slave on the remote machine and it can call any script you like. Another alternative is Rundeck. It can ssh into the remote machine and run commands. Perhaps Rundeck is more to your liking because it also has a command-line interface for executing jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sshexec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) task can do the work. Obviously Ant should be installed on the build machine. But you have to install a `ssh` server on the build machine too.

Here a piece of build.xml for your local machine:

```
<sshexec host="buildmachine"
username="builduser"
password="somepassword"
command="ant -f /path/to/the/build.xml" />
```

Comment: we have a tool named freessh, but it requires admin rights to UP the SSH service every time system is restarted. Can u pls help me with an tool which does not require admin rights..??

Comment: You need something which listen on the network to know when to launch the build. And it needs to stay up even upon restart. So at some point you must have some admin right. At least once to setup a ssh server which automatically start up at the machine boot time.